# Dockerfile maybe not good. Application won't start

Tags: python, linux, docker, dockerfile

I have an API build with python and fastapi that works on localhost but when I move it on a Linux machine it loads the image but would not run. I am using: `docker run -d -p 10701:8000 fastapi-docker` to run it but when I type `docker ps` it shows that it is not running. Here is the docker file:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR /fastapi-app

RUN mkdir -p /app/pdfs
VOLUME /app/pdfs

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app ./app
# COPY ./pdfs ./pdfs 

# Installing Oracle instant client
WORKDIR    /opt/oracle
RUN        apt-get update && apt-get install -y libaio1 wget unzip \
        && wget 
https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient- 
basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
        && unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
        && rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip \
        && cd /opt/oracle/instantclient* \
        && rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *README *jar uidrvci genezi adrci \
        && echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle- 
instantclient.conf \
        && ldconfig
WORKDIR /fastapi-app
CMD ["python", "./app/main.py"]
```

Can someone please tell me why it is not working? Thanks in advance

I tried running it on localhost and the error is: `urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/fastapi-app/popriri.xsd'>` but I have copied the file and I still get this error: `COPY ./popriri.xsd ./fastapi-app`

Comment: Add a `RUN ll -a` step in your dockerfile and build to see the file/folder structure you have.

Comment: Isn't popiri.xsd saved in /fastapi-app/app?